# upload excel to server

Tags: php, excel, upload

i work on a website and have a small problem.
i want an upload an excel file on my Server.
I did something like that before with pictures (upload profilpicture). Is it possible to change that code for excel files?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Profil.php" method="POST">                  
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" id="Upload" name="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
```

AND the script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
//
{

    $target_dir = "Profilbilder/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $filename = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
    $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name
    $newfilename = $_SESSION['loginUsername'].$file_ext ;
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) 
    {
        //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else 
    {
        //echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }   
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) 
    {
        //echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) 
    {

        //echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) 
    {
        //echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else 
    {
        //if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$newfilename)) 
        {           
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else 
        {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

change this string

```
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"&& $imageFileType != "gif" )
```

to be something like this

```
if($file_ext != "xls" && $file_ext != "xlsx" && $file_ext != "csv")
```

its quick and dirty and there's better ways of doing it checking for meta's but it'll work.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

Should note its massively insecure as there's nothing stopping you renaming a .exe to a .xls and then uploading or so.  Checking the meta type of the uploaded file is probably better.

Comment: Now the code run until the upload. but move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$newfilename) doesnt works. have u an idea?

Comment: you need to remove the getimagesize and the if check statement relating to that too incase you haven't already. also make sure your file save path is writable by the webserver